# How to read a single row or of multiple txt files in python

Tags: python, list, tuples, text-files, file-handling

I am trying to open a txt file from a folder which contains several txt files. But I want to choose the file as a user input- means the user should put the txt file name and the output will be the data in that respective txt file. Can someone help me with this?

I tried like this:

```py
import os
os.chdir(r"D:\Thesis\data\new_data\HKSS")
filelist=os.listdir(r"D:\Thesis\data\new_data\HKSS")
mylines=[]
for file in filelist:
   with open("241Pu.txt", "rt") as myfile:
      for i in myfile:
         mylines.append(i.strip("\n"))
      tup=(mylines[0], mylines[1])
      str="".join(tup)
      print(str)
      myfile.close()
```

But the output is coming like:

```
E(MeV)   N(/fission)
```

There are values under **E** and **N** which I am not sure how to get through the above program. Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: If you are using `with` clause for file resource management, then you don't need to explicitly call `myfile.close()`.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Why are you iterating over `file list` when you ignore `x` and repeatedly open the same `241Pu.txt` file? Why aren't you using `input` to get a file name from the user?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do? Why are you iterating over *filelist*? It looks like you're trying to merge alternate lines. What does 241Pu.txt look like (just a fragment)?

Comment: Hi, my text file has two columns , one is the E column with column of values and another is the N coloumn with coloumn of values. I want to write this program in such a way so that when I enter the filename the program will give the data of that particular text file. My HKSS folder has 4 text files.